# Can I make Apache not care about directories it can't access?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have several instances where users seemingly have changed their mind about material that they previously had available on the web, and therefore they have recursively protected a whole directory as `drwx------`.

Apache gets understandably nervous when it can't read `.htaccess` files and gives [core:crit] error messages about it being "unable to check htaccess file ".

The users could have moved the material somewhere else and have something explicit done in `.htaccess`, but given that this is how they protected the material, can I get Apache to just accept that it can't access those files (and therefore of course not serve them), and that there is nothing amiss because of it to avoid unnecessary error messages?

Comment: It probably can - you can also use a cannon to kill a fly - move the directory!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious issue here is that these users, by doing that, are affecting service on the server, which should be part of your terms and conditions.

However, if you really need to disable `.htaccess` files because they are throwing errors, you can set `AllowOverride None` for specific directories.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really won't to disable .htaccess because it should be used again if Apache later can access it again. I just think that "can't serve this because can't access .htaccess" isn't a big deal when "can't serve this because can't access it" anyway. (If there is no good solution I will just continue to collect uninteresting crit errors.)

Comment: That's pretty much all you can do then I think. If it's not causing problems then it isn't the end of the world, just very annoying.

Comment: @pst you want apache to not freak out about not having access but you don't want to set allowoverride none, so you want to go left and right at the same time. Can't do that.

Comment: Oh well. I don't think it's unreasonable, since the real reason for Apache to "freak out" about not being able to check .htaccess is that it might otherwise serve something that .htaccess says it shouldn't. So as far as I understand it could check things in another order instead and just refuse without worry if it can't even get to the resource.